# Download excel files from sharepoint RESTAPI Office365

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, office365api, office-automation

When trying to download Excel files located in SharePoint into my Cloudera Workbench Directory,
I get the following error

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File


app_principal = {
'site_url' : 'https://XXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXX',
'client_id' : 'XXXXXXXX',
'client_secret' : 'XXXXXXXX',
'folder_url_shrpt' : """/sites/XXXXXXXX/Shared%20Documents/General/Testing_data"""
}

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(app_principal['site_url'])
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_principal['client_id'], client_secret=app_principal['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(app_principal['site_url'], ctx_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()

print('Authenticated into sharepoint as: ',web.properties['Title'])

file_url = """/sites/XXXXXXXX/Shared%20Documents/General/Testing_data/train_data.xlsx"""
download_path = pathlib.Path().resolve() / "download_file.xlsx"
with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
    file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(file_url).download(local_file).execute_query()
    #file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(file_url).download(local_file).execute_query()
print("[Ok] file has been downloaded into: {0}".format(download_path))


--------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ClientRequestException: (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException', 'The file 
/sites/XXXXXXXXX/Shared%20Documents/General/Testing_data/train_data.xlsx does not exist.', "404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXXXX/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath......
```

I took the code from Github https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/download_file.py

Please help!